# Why writing an Inner Private class inside <> bracket of outer class makes error?

Tags: java, generics, private, inner-classes

I'm trying to insert a private class into brackets (Generics) of outer class declaration and getting the next error : "com.example.gridrecyclerview.RecyclerViewAdapter.VieHolder has private access in com.example.gridrecyclerview.RecyclerViewAdapter"

When changing inner class to *public* everything ok. Can someone explain me the issue.
Attached code:

```
    package com.example.gridrecyclerview;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;

public class RecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter <RecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder> {
    Context context;
    List<ModelItem> modelItemList;

    public RecyclerViewAdapter(Context context, List<ModelItem> modelItemList)
    {
        this.context = context;
        this.modelItemList = modelItemList;
    }

    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType)
    {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.rc_item,parent,false);
        return new ViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position)
    {
        Log.e("onBindViewHolder ","onBindViewHolder");
        ModelItem modelItem = modelItemList.get(position);
        holder.firstNameTextView.setText(modelItem.getFirstName());
        holder.secondNameText.setText(modelItem.getLastName());
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount()
    {
        return modelItemList.size();
    }

    private class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder
    {

        TextView firstNameTextView;
        TextView secondNameText;
        public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView)
        {
            super(itemView);
            firstNameTextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.first_name);
            secondNameText = itemView.findViewById(R.id.second_name);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Leaving aside generics, do you think you should be able to write a public method that returns (or has parameters) of types that aren't private? If someone wrote a method of `public static PrivateClass getPrivateClassInstance()` what would you expect the compiler to do with any code calling that method? Apply the same logic in your situation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer this question you should know what happened behind the scene when you use generics in Java, Generics are checked at compile time and there is no generic type at runtime this is called type erasure, when you compile your program all generics are castes to their specific types. Imagine your `RecyclerView.Adapter` class is something as follow:

```
public class Adapter<T> {
    T view;

    public T getView() {
        return view;
    }

    public void setView(T view) {
        this.view = view;
    }
}
```

And Imagine you have defined your `RecyclerViewAdapter` class as before:

Now lets discuss this problem from two points of view:

1. Programmer
2. Compiler

As a programmer imagine somewhere in another class you create an instance of `RecyclerViewAdapter` class as follow and call getView() on that object:

```
RecyclerViewAdapter recycler = RecyclerViewAdapter();
? object =  recycler.getView()
```

What type of object you put here instead of ?
clearly you can't put `RecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder` because it is private for `RecyclerViewAdapter` and you can't use it elsewhere.

Now lets consider this problem from compiler point of view:

When compiling generics, compiler use erasure and compile your code to something like this:

```
RecyclerViewAdapter recycler = RecyclerViewAdapter();
? object =  (RecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder)recycler.getView();
```

Here you can see compiler cast the type of your object at compile time(`(RecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder)recycler.getView()`). But is it possible for compiler to do something like this here?

Of course not because `RecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder` is private for `RecyclerViewAdapter` class while this code is written in another class.

Comment: thanks. I think i understand most of your explanation. I didn't understand your's  mean when you wrote: "*So you should have a public interface which RecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder implements that"*, and also does the part that came after it (the snippets with the casting), is it related to the interface suggestion?

Comment: For the first part I edited my answer to make it clear, and the casting part is not related to interface it is related to type erasure. when compiler check the type at compile time it cast the object type to the exact type of object, when compiler compiles your code the return type of `getView()` method is `RecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolde` so it cast that object to its exact type. And at runtime you don't have something like T, every object are casted to their exact types.

Comment: what is the method in the interface that **RecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder** class in your example implements? All your answer is really awesome, but i really want to understand the interface meaning and still unfortunately can't

Comment: @Eitanos30 Forget about `interface` it was my mistake to mention that here, It made this answer complicate I've just edited my answer read it again please.

Comment: Ok (although it was great to understand the interface issue :)  ) . Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can not do this, because there you are passing the private class to "RecyclerView.Adapter" class. In other words, the ViewHolder class only available inside the RecyclerViewAdapter class.

PS: You can create this class as a new Class, then pass it through "RecyclerView.Adapter" class or change it to public scope.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I know that i can turn it to public and everything will work but i want to understand why the current code isn't working. You wrote:*"You can not do this, because there you are passing the private class to "RecyclerView.Adapter" class. In other words, the ViewHolder class only available inside the RecyclerViewAdapter class"*. Does the signature of  RecyclerViewAdapte is part of it's class?

Comment: Here the problem is not related to RecyclerViewAdapter class, the problem is "RecyclerView.Adapter <RecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder>" because of the scope of RecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder, private class instance only available in RecyclerViewAdapter class that is why for "RecyclerView.Adapter" "RecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder" class is not accessible. Yes, it looks weird but in generics, although RecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter it doesn't mean RecyclerView.Adapter is in the signature of RecyclerViewAdapter.

Answer (score 0):

As per the accessibility rule in [Java-Spec](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/jls8.pdf) Page -164, a private member declared is accessible only within the body of the top level class. I hope body of the class means not the definition of it.

**
*Otherwise, the member or constructor is declared private, and access is permitted if and only if it occurs within the body of the top level class (§7.6) that encloses the declaration of the member or constructor.*
**

Comment: Thanks! Sorry that i can only approve only one answer. Thanks again